# using multiple before action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am trying to make the route private, the case is like this:
if user want to go `'galleries/:id'`
it gonna redirect to `gallery/login?id=:id`
and on that `gallery_login_path` html, I make a login form into to that gallery with required PIN

route.rb:

```
  resources :galleries
  get 'gallery/login', to: 'galleries#login', as: 'gallery_login'
  post 'gallery/auth', to: 'galleries#auth', as: 'gallery_auth'

//

gallery GET    /galleries/:id
gallery_login GET    /gallery/login
gallery_auth POST   /gallery/auth
```

that form gonna trigger to URL: `gallery_auth_path`, the method us like this :

```
  def auth
    @error_login
    @gallery = Gallery.find_by(id: params[:gallery_id])
    if @gallery.pin.nil?
      redirect_to "galleries/#{@gallery.id}"
    elsif  @gallery.pin == params[:pin] && @gallery.expired_pin.past?
      @error_login = 'PIN expired'
    elsif @gallery.pin == params[:pin] && !@gallery.expired_pin.past?
      redirect_to "/galleries/#{@gallery.id}"
      true
    else
      @error_login = 'PIN not match'
    end
    @error_login = 'Required PIN' unless params[:pin].present?
    if @error_login.present?
      respond_to do |format|
        @error_login
        format.js {render 'galleries/error_login' , layout: false}
      end
    end
  end
```

on `login.html.haml` :

```
    = form_with url: gallery_auth_path do |f|
      = hidden_field_tag :gallery_id, "#{params[:id]}"
      .form-group.row
        = f.label :pin, class: 'col-sm-2 col-form-label text-center'
        .col-sm-4.col-md-4.col-xs-4
          = f.text_field :pin, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'PIN'
      .form-group
        .col-sm-4
          = f.submit 'Login', data: {disable_with: 'Loading...'}, class: 'btn btn-primary '
```

when the user input wrong PIN, the error message on login.html was work fine, but when the PIN is correct , it can't trigger to 'galleries/:id'

in my galleries_controller:

```
before_action :authenticate, only: [:show]
  def login
  end 

  def auth
    // method on above 
  end

  private 

  def authenticate
    redirect_to "/gallery/login?id=#{params[:id]}"
  end
```

am i wrong using before_action for this case ? is there any way to correct this way? 
because on gallery login form after user put a correct pin, it can't trigger to 'galleries/:id' because oif before_action i bet ,

Comment: Your `before_action` will only be executed for the `show` action, but I don't see a `show` action in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Change `params[:pin]` with `params[:gallery][:pin]` in controller method

## routes.rb

```
get 'gallery/login', to: 'galleries#login', as: 'gallery_login'
post 'gallery/auth', to: 'galleries#auth', as: 'gallery_auth'
resources :galleries
```

Comment: what is that for? which method?? there is no error on my html page, but it just can't trigger to 'galleries/:id' when login to gallery success i tried to redirect to 'galleries/:id' and it become a return to login again

Comment: change `@gallery.pin == params[:pin]` with `@gallery.pin == params[:gallery][:pin]` inside auth method

Comment: can i know why ? i am trying to test it again now

Comment: if you check params, `pin` is present inside `gallery` key

Comment: it doesnt work , it said: NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass:

Comment: can you check whats the paramaters in controller?

Comment: {"authenticity_token"=>"Kfzt5+44bipRDG4g+u/5MEjASx5zUa5EkszAaTWfv2o4b0egD7r/BiaC0rQjGP5GAxJnARWFkDA+3dWLQkj1KQ==", "gallery_id"=>"3cf52597-6ebb-4eb9-b325-6511ff91014c", "pin"=>"12345", "commit"=>"Login"}

Comment: i think this is because the before_action, because after before_action 'galleries/:id' must log in on the page i redirect, and after success put a pin it go to galleries/:id again and return back to log in again :(, this is why i ask how to resolve kind this case

Comment: `resources :galleries
  get 'gallery/login', to: 'galleries#login', as: 'gallery_login'
  post 'gallery/auth', to: 'galleries#auth', as: 'gallery_auth'`

Comment: it is same like the problem i mention first time, it return back to login gallery page, , if you curios try this ngrok link from my local : https://52f0746c.ngrok.io/galleries/3cf52597-6ebb-4eb9-b325-6511ff91014c , PIN : 12345 , and put wrong pin also

Comment: before_action: :authentication, only %[show]  #this gonna trigger to login page gallery, and login with correct pin then it trigger to login gallery again

Comment: You need to change tour `before_action`. As it is written right now, whenever someone hits `galleries/#{gallery_id}`, it ALWAYS redirects to the login action.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit hard to understand...you want to use multiple before_actions? To do that just add more rules.

```
before_action :authenticate, only: [:show]
before_action :is_admin?, only: [:create]
```

Also, the first comment on your post says that you don't have the action `show`.  Where is that at, your authenticate is only going to be called before that action.